# Why can't I insert this png?

Tags: graphics, pdf, png

I just wanted to insert this png (see attachment), but I get a bunch of errors
-> undefined control sequence

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Zürich Plan}
\date{text}
\author{text}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  
  \section{text}
    \subsection{Next} 

    \subsection{text}
  
  \section{text}
 
  
  \section{text}
  
  \section{Hello}
 \includegraphics[width=200, height=400]{code.png}}

    
  \end{document}
```

The png is in the same folder as the latex document[image: code.png]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please tell us more about the error message you get. Which control sequence is undefined?

Comment: Using `fontspec` implies you use xelatex as your compiler, thus remove `pdftex` from your class options. Additionally, height and width need a unit.

Comment: Besides the issues mentioned by @leandriis you are referring to a pdf once and then to a png. Is it a PDF or a PNG?

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pdfximage 
                      \ifnum 0\ifx \Gin@decode \@empty \else 1\fi \ifGin@int...
l.32 ...egraphics[width=200, height=400]{code.png}
                                                  }
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct

Comment: @leandriis what do you mean with remove "pdftex from your class"? I'm quite new to latex...

Comment: Replace `\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper, 10pt]{article}` with `\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}`

Comment: @MerkurWeimer: Which compiler do you use? And did you also add the missing units to the width and height options of your `\includegraphics` command?

Comment: thanks a lot it works all fine now!

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted an answer saying what was the problem instead of leaving us wondering.  (And for future questions, please edit the error message into the original question instead of putting it in a comment.)

Comment: By the way, if you're wanting to display Python code in your document, the `listings` (or `minted`) package would be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following code:

```
    % !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Zürich Plan}
\date{text}
\author{text}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  
  \section{text}
    \subsection{Next} 

    \subsection{text}
  
  \section{text}
 
  
  \section{text}
  
  \section{Hello}
 \includegraphics[width=200pt, height=400pt]{code.png} %corrected
    
  \end{document}
```

In my system `fontspec` is not compatible with pdflatex, so I commented it.

Note the initial line `% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex` to invoque  `pdflatex` if it is not the default, as in my case. It is called `magic comment`.

In the `\includegraphics` of your code you need to include the units (pt I guessed).

Good luck.

[image]